# how to assign uploaded file to the property of object and send as data to the post http in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is post here is my code

html :-

```
<form>
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload" file-model="obj.file">
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="obj.name">
    <input type="text" name="city" ng-model="obj.city">
<button type="button" ng-click="uploadFile()"></button>
</form>
```

Directive to read the file when choosing file form html:---

```
angular.module('iscopeNewUiApp.appcore')
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Controller code to send this form data to http post :---

inside controller there is a uploadFile() method

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(){
var file,name,city;
file = $scope.obj.file;
name = $scope.obj.name;
city = $scope.obj.city;
var fd = new FormData();
var attribute = "<attributes>
                   <name>name</name>
                    <city>city</city>
                </attributes>"

fd.append('executefile', file);
fd.append('attributes', attributes);

 $http.post("http://hyperion.iscope.innominds:8181/iscope-metadata/rest/resource/uploadfile", fd, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
                }).success(function(resp){
                    console.log(resp);
                }).error(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                })
}
```

actually i suppose to send data like this

```
fd = {'executefile': file,'attributes', <attributes><name>sdsd</name><city>sdsd</city></attributes>};


but when i tried with above code it is going like below

   ------WebKitFormBoundaryo2MKUAGw2aE8CGU6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="executefile"; filename="dropDownWithLiveSearch.html"
Content-Type: text/html


------WebKitFormBoundaryo2MKUAGw2aE8CGU6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attributes"

<attributes><name>sdsd</name><city>sdsd</city></attributes>
------WebKitFormBoundaryo2MKUAGw2aE8CGU6--
```

here is example https://jsfiddle.net/ZG9re/6400/

can any one suggest me how to send file and remaining data in one object?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many Angular modules written by community to do file uploading. These two have explicit support for older browsers:

- https://github.com/leon/angular-upload - uses iframes as a fallback
- https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload - uses FileAPI/Flash as a fallback

A couple of more options:

And some other options:

- https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/
- https://github.com/uor/angular-file
- https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload

If you don't want to use any of those you can write your own using File api:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", $scope.file);
```

And then add this to your ajax call:

```
data: {
        formdata
    }
```